# add/remove static route from route table by LINUX KERNEL MODULE

Tags: static, linux-kernel, routes, addition

I'm working on a project, that I am implementing via kernel-mode module in Linux,
at some callback (inside the kernel) I need to modify routing table, for example 
I may need to delete a static route, or add a static route to routing tables.
I know we can do it simply in Linux user mode, but I need do it in kernel mode,
after reading some `Linux source code / iproute` package I think it should be related to function `fn_hash_insert` but i failed to find a good documentation for these commands, like `MSDN`.

Thanks

Comment: Linux kernel has no documentation as  qualitative as MSDN. On reason is that kernel's API evolves rapidly. E.g., function you refer (`fn_hash_insert`) is absent in the current kernel. What kernel's version you use, and what high level API function you want to use (`fn_hash_insert` is just callback).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i use Ubuntu 15.04 with kernel (3.19.8)--- (what high level API i want to use?) i dont know much about different module of linux kernel that is available also in kernel mode. what is different module available for manipulating routing table?